# Spring MVC Based Rest Services Validations for request body

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-restcontroller

I have Rest Controller in my application which has the code snippet like below:-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserRestControllerV1 {

    @PostMapping("")
    public Response registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid final Request<UserDto> request,
                             final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                             BindingResult result){
    Response response = new Response(request);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        response.setData(new String("Error"));
    }else {
        response.setData(new String("Test"));
    }
    return response;
}
```

The Request Class:-

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Request<T> {
    @JsonProperty(value = "co-relation-id")
    private String coRelationID;

    @NotNull(message = "The request body should be present")
    private T data;

    /*
     ..... various other fields
     Getters / Setters
    */
}
```

The UserDto Class :-

```
public class UserDto {

    @NotNull(message = "The username should not be null")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "The password should not be null")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    /*
     ..... various other fields
     Getters / Setters
    */    
}
```

Issue : I am having issues with my validations here. The field `private T data` in the request class gets validated but the fields inside T - in the case UserDto are not getting validated.

So I need to know the approach or code snippet to achieve this.

I have tried configuring the hibernate validator bean in the configuration but it is of no help in the scenario

Comment: put `@Valid ` on `private T data;`

Comment: thanks that works, but what if I want to have a validation check on the data field also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Valid constraint will instruct the Bean Validator to delve to the type of its applied property and validate all constraints found there.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Request<T> {
  @JsonProperty(value = "co-relation-id")
  private String coRelationID;

  //@NotNull(message = "The request body should be present")
  @Valid
  private T data;

  /*
   ..... various other fields
   Getters / Setters
  */
}
```

Comment: thanks that works, but what if I want to have a validation check on the data field also?